# Is Marshal.ReleaseComObject really necessary when using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel?

Tags: excel-interop

I have a mid sized code library (several thousand lines) that uses Excel Interop (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel).

The program that keeps a workbook open for hours at a time, and does manipulations like adding/editing text, shapes, and calling macros.

I have not once seen a Marshal.ReleaseComObject. Yet, the users don't report any problems.

In all cases, the objects go out of scope within several seconds.

So, is this a problem? How? If yes, how do I justify to management that it needs cleanup? If not, why recommend it in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, but I did a lot of Excel automation from .NET. I never used Marshal.ReleaseComObject either. Never saw a problem.